# Counting spatial points within a polygon according to a temporal window

Tags: r, gis, temporal

## Overview

Using R, I would like to count the number of points within a polygon according to a specific criterion (a temporal window).

I have the following data:

1. Geo-located survey data that include the date of the survey interview. Thus, I am able to pinpoint exactly when and where each survey was conducted and to map them out across the United States.
2. Geo-located data about political rallies across the United States. These also include the date.

Using QGIS, I created a set of circular 50 mile buffers around each survey respondent. My goal is to count the number of political rallies that falls within each respondent's "buffer" within a specific time frame preceding the interview. The 50 mile buffers created in QGIS retain all variables of the original data, including the date of the interview.

## Data

Using QGIS, I created some [mock shapefiles](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e6fvcdrkieody0j/AADzXTzeHUIPtm69G8SzX_i1a?dl=0) with dates and locations to aid in replication.

## Approach

I am trying to use `GISTools::poly.counts` to count the number of rallies within different temporal windows (30 days, 90 days, etc.).

Generally, to count the number of points within a polygon, I would simply use:

```
count <- GISTools::poly.counts(rallies, buffer)
```

This gives me the total number of rallies that occur within each buffer, but doesn't allow me to specify temporal windows. For example, it would be great to develop a count of the number of rallies within a buffer for the 30 days preceding the survey interview as well as the 90 days preceding the interview.

Remember, each polygon within my `buffer` shapefile has a different date of interview.

Here's what I've tried, but it's not working:

```
buffer$count_30 <- GISTools::poly.counts(
    rallies[buffer$date - rallies$date > 0 & buffer$date - rallies$date <= 30], 
    buffer)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: "*Unfortunately, I cannot share the data to aid in reproducibility.*" Surely you can create a small illustrative example with fake data? Say, 2 rallies, 10 surveys... we don't need much, but it's very hard to debug code without data to run it on.

Comment: As stated by Gregor, you should at least state how the data is structured - i.e dataframes, lists etc..

Comment: Dear @GregorThomas and dvd280, thank you for your responses. I have created some mock data shapefiles with dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer using `sf`, but this time using spatial joins and dplyr for filtering etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)


rallies <- read_sf('Downloads/stack_ex_q/rallies.shp')
# Here I don't use the supplied buffer, but make one according to the data
#fifty_buff <- read_sf('Downloads/stack_ex_q/rallies.shp') 
surveys <- read_sf('Downloads/stack_ex_q/surveys.shp')


# Transform to a crs using meters as a distance & make date col a proper date
rallies <- st_transform(rallies, crs = 2163) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
surveys <- st_transform(surveys, crs = 2163) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))

# make a buffer w/ 50 mile radius (80467 meters), not used but useful for visualization
buffer_50mi <- st_buffer(surveys, dist = 80467)
```

Plot the data for a quick visual check:

```
library(mapview)
mapview(rallies, col.regions = 'purple') + 
  mapview(surveys, col.regions = 'black') + 
  mapview(buffer_50mi, col.regions = 'green')
```

[image: Visual check of the data]

Join the data using st_is_within_distance, using 80467m = 50 miles.

```
joined <- surveys %>%
  st_join(rallies, join = st_is_within_distance, 80467)

head(joined)

Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1350401 ymin: -556609 xmax: 1438586 ymax: -455743.1
projected CRS:  NAD27 / US National Atlas Equal Area
# A tibble: 6 x 5
   id.x date.x                geometry  id.y date.y    
  <dbl> <date>             <POINT [m]> <dbl> <date>    
1     1 2020-04-26   (1350401 -556609)    16 2020-02-19
2     1 2020-04-26   (1350401 -556609)    17 2020-05-12
3     2 2020-03-27 (1438586 -455743.1)     7 2020-02-18
4     2 2020-03-27 (1438586 -455743.1)    15 2020-07-01
5     2 2020-03-27 (1438586 -455743.1)    15 2020-03-28
6     3 2020-06-12 (1352585 -479940.5)    15 2020-07-01
```

The .x columns are from the survey sf object & the .y columns are from the rallies sf object. Geometry is retained from the survey sf.

Using dplyr's filter, group_by, and mutate, find what you're looking for.  The code below counts rallies within 50 miles and +/- 60 days by survey point as an example.

```
joined_60days <- joined %>% 
  group_by(id.x) %>%
  mutate(date_diff = as.numeric(date.x - date.y)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(date_diff)) %>%  ## remove survey points with no rallies in 50mi/60d
  filter(abs(date_diff) <= 60) %>%
  group_by(id.x) %>%
  count()

head(joined_60days)

Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1268816 ymin: -556609 xmax: 1438586 ymax: -322572.4
projected CRS:  NAD27 / US National Atlas Equal Area
# A tibble: 4 x 3
   id.x     n            geometry
  <dbl> <int>         <POINT [m]>
1     1     1   (1350401 -556609)
2     2     2 (1438586 -455743.1)
3     3     1 (1352585 -479940.5)
4     4     2 (1268816 -322572.4)
```

Quick visual check:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I approached your problem in a different way by using the `sf` package instead of `GISTools`. The algorithm is straightforward and you can easily adapt it to your `GISTools::poly.counts()` method:

1. Read in shapefiles (`st_read()`)
2. Filter shapefiles by date using `dplyr` (make sure you've got Date objects to create the windows)
3. Find the intersection of whichever points data with the rally buffer (`st_intersection()`)
4. Get the size of the intersection object (`nrow()`)

Likely you'll have to tweak the function parameters to make sure it works correctly for the real data. Below is an example using your mock data.

Setup and read in the data (note `stringsAsFactors=F` just makes the dates easier to create; not necessary for R version 4.x).

```
require(tidyverse)
require(magritter) #adds the %<>% operator
require(sf)
require(lubridate)
rally <- st_read(dsn=getwd(),layer='rallies',stringsAsFactors = F)
buff <- st_read(dsn=getwd(),layer='50m_buffer',stringsAsFactors = F)
surv <- st_read(dsn=getwd(),layer='surveys',stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Create the date objects.

```
rally %<>% mutate(date=ymd(date))
buff %<>% mutate(date=ymd(date))
surv %<>% mutate(date=ymd(date))

window <- c(ymd('2020-03-27')-30, ymd('2020-03-27')+30)
```

Filter the data using the temporal window.

```
buffSub <- buff %>% 
  filter(date>=window[1] & date<=window[2])

rallySub <- rally %>% 
  filter(date>=window[1] & date<=window[2])
```

Get the number if intersecting points.

```
intersectObject <- st_intersection(rallySub, buffSub)
nrow(intersectObject)
```

Or if you want to use the days since a rally or something along those lines you can create new columns in whichever points object which represent the time difference between a rally and an active buffer and use those values to filter.

Loop through the dates for each rally and get the time difference with each buffer.

```
daysDiff <- data.frame(t(sapply(rally$date, function(d) d-buff$date)))
```

Add those columns to the data and rename with buff1, buff2, etc.

```
rallyNew <- bind_cols(rally, daysDiff) %>%
  rename_with(~gsub('X', 'buff', .x))
```

Use those values to filter. Go one column at a time, filter, and get the intersection with buffer associated with that column.

```
WINDOW=20
for(i in 4:ncol(rallyNew)){
  rallySub <- rallyNew %>% 
    filter(get(unlist(names(rallyNew))[i])<WINDOW &
             get(unlist(names(rallyNew))[i])>-WINDOW)
  intersectObject <- st_intersection(rallySub, buffSub[i-3,])
  print(nrow(intersectObject))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @J Thompson! This didn't quite solve the issue because the approach, as far as I can tell, has static date ranges (rather than adapting to each survey). But I really do appreciate the help!